# How to check total amount of entries in a channel

Tags: channel-entries, ee

If I'm using expression engine just using backend (for example I just write the blogs I don't code with the developer), no exposure to the code, how do I view the total amount of entries?

How do I filter those entries to show me how many drafts, how many published and so on?

Seems trivial but I don't know the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you view the Channel Entries list (Content->Edit) there are a number of filters available.

[image]

You can use the dropdowns to show entries from a particular channel, category, or status. There is no explicit total of entries shown but you can easily determine it from looking at the number of 'pages' there are in the listing. The list can be sorted by clicking on the column headings.

You may find that you don't have access to this list. It's dependant on how your member group has been set up.

It is also possible to set up some front-end templates which will show you the number of entries etc.

Comment: May I ask another question? @foamcow , I found that you can also find number of entries if you use the database in 'Database Query Form'. What will the query be if I want to get all the channel_videos from a channel? I want to see how many entries have videos.

Comment: I don't use Channel Videos so I don't know how its data is organised. I imagine it could be quite complex. Sorry.

Comment: no problem, it should just be a quick check of whether that field is empty or not, hope so at least